# groupby aggregate does not work as expected for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need some help with aggregation and joining the dataframe groupby output.

Here is my dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2020/08/18','2020/08/18', '2020/08/18', '2020/08/18', '2020/08/18', '2020/08/18', '2020/08/18'],
    'Time':['Val3',60,30,'Val2',60,60,'Val2'],
    'Val1': [0, 53.5, 33.35, 0,53.5, 53.5,0],
    'Val2':[0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 35],
    'Val3':[48.5,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'Place':['LOC_A','LOC_A','LOC_A','LOC_B','LOC_B','LOC_B','LOC_A']
})
```

I want following result:

```
   Place  Total_sum  Factor  Val2_new
0  LOC_A      86.85   21.71       35
1  LOC_B     107.00   26.75       45
```

I have tried following:

```
df_by_place = df.groupby('Place')['Val1'].sum().reset_index(name='Total_sum')
df_by_place['Factor'] = round(df_by_place['Total_sum']*0.25, 2)
df_by_place['Val2_new'] = df.groupby('Place')['Val2'].agg('sum')
print(df_by_place)
```

But I get following result:

```
   Place  Total_sum  Factor  Val2_new
0  LOC_A      86.85   21.71       NaN
1  LOC_B     107.00   26.75       NaN
```

When I do following operation by it self:

```
print(df.groupby('Place')['Val2'].agg('sum'))
Output is desired:
Place
LOC_A    35
LOC_B    45
```

But when I assign to a column it gives "NaN" value.

Any help to this issue would be appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: ``df_by_place['Val2_new'] = df.groupby('Place')['Val2'].agg('sum').reset_index(drop=True)``

Answer (score 0):

Groupby in pandas >= 0.25 will allow you to assign names to columns inside of it and do what you want in one go.

```
df.groupby('Place').agg(Total_sum = ('Val1','sum'),
                        Factor = ('Val1', lambda x: round((x * 0.25).sum(),2)),
                        Val2_new = ('Val2', 'sum')).reset_index()
```

This provides your desired result.

```
    Place   Total_sum   Factor  Val2_new
0   LOC_A   86.85       21.71   35
1   LOC_B   107.00      26.75   45
```

Using lambda functions within groupby will make things a lot neater!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by sushanth seems to hold good.

> `df_by_place['Val2_new'] = df.groupby('Place')['Val2'].agg('sum').reset_index(drop=True)`

By assigning drop = True in reset_index the previously created index are removed and the new index/column_name given by user is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

slight variation on @maishm's answer, but basically same idea:

```
df.groupby('Place').agg(total_sum=pd.NamedAgg(column='Val1', aggfunc=sum), 
                        factor=pd.NamedAgg(column='Val1', aggfunc=lambda x: round(sum(x)*0.25,2)), 
                        val2_new=pd.NamedAgg(column='Val2', aggfunc=sum)).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   Place  total_sum  factor  val2_new
0  LOC_A      86.85   21.71        35
1  LOC_B     107.00   26.75        45
```

Comment: Thank you Derek Eden, @marishm and Susanth for your response.  I tried Derek and it worked like Charm.  Thank you so much for your help.